# Access to elements of $_

Tags: powershell, pipeline

In order to create symlinks in PowerShell, you need to use the following command :

```
New-Item -Path C:\temp\myLink -Target C:\Users\{me}\Documents\target.txt -ItemType SymbolicLink
```

I would like to implement a more straightforward syntax as shown below :

```
"C:\temp\myLink", "C:\Users\{me}\Documents\target.txt" | Ln
```

`Ln` is a filter defined as such :

```
filter Ln {
     New-Item -Path $_[0] -Target  $_[1] -ItemType SymbolicLink
}
```

However, it doesn't work, and I would like to know how to access single elements of `$_`, for instance in our case shouldn't we have `$_[0] == "C:\temp\myLink"` ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Currently your filter is processing each element being passed through the pipeline, if you want to pass in the whole array (both elements), you would need to use this syntax: `, ("C:\temp\myLink", "C:\Users\{me}\Documents\target.txt") | Ln`

Comment: Thanks ! I will adopt Santiago Squarzon solution but this is always good to know !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the syntax proposed in your question an easy workaround would be to change your [`filter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.2#filters) for a *non-advanced* [`function`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.2) and utilize the [automatic variable `$input`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#input) to collect both paths being passed through the pipeline:

```
function Ln {
    $params = @($input)
    if($params.Count -ne 2) {
        throw 'Unsoported!'
    }
    New-Item -Path $params[0] -Target $params[1] -ItemType SymbolicLink
}

"C:\temp\myLink", "C:\Users\{me}\Documents\target.txt" | Ln
```

Answer (score 1):

When you pipe values like this they are fed one at a time. You can test this with a little "debug" version of your filter

```
filter Ln {
     write-host $_[0] -ForeGroundColor Cyan
     Write-Host $_[1] -ForeGroundColor Green
}
```

You will see it's a single string that we are grabbing the first and second character from

[image]

If you want to send both elements together

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#comma-operator-